# How to prevent dbReadTable from changing column names

Tags: r, r-dbi

I am using the `DBI` package to read data from a SQL Server database. The function `dbReadTable` automatically changes the columns names to replace spaces with dots.

Is there a way to control what get replace by what and or to not change anything?

The reason for this is, earlier I was using `RODBC` package with `sqlQuery` function which does not change the column names and there is a lot of code already written with old column names.

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on the *DBI* backend you're using. You could try:

```
dbReadTable(..., check.names = FALSE)
```

If you need a custom renaming strategy (e.g. replacing spaces by underscores) you need to read in with names unchanged and implement the renaming yourself:

```
clean_names <- function(x) {
  gsub(" ", "_", x)
}

data <- dbReadTable(.......)
names(data) <- clean_names(names(data))
```

Comment: Thanks! This works for keeping the column names intact but can I control the replacement for space? Also what does    DBI backend mean?

Comment: Can you please rephrase "replacement for space"? See https://www.r-dbi.org/ for a very brief overview.

Comment: "replacement for space": by default dbReadTable replaces a space in the column name with a dot. I want to replace the space in column name by an underscore "_" instead.

Comment: @AshishSinghal: Edited answer.